# Can you invalidate a specific user's session on deactivate?

Tags: python, django, session, logout, invalidation

I define a deactivate method on a proxy class for the Django User model to prevent them from logging in (if they are past-due, for example), however if they are still logged in I would like to invalidate all of their sessions.

Is there a Django-sanctioned or Pythonic way to do this?

Since Sessions are encoded it is not preferable to iterate through them and decode each one to find the ones associated with this user. I have looked at invalidating sessions on password change, which Django supports, but in my case the user is not changing their own password, rather I am forcing them to log out. Here is my CustomUser model:

```
class CustomUser(User):
        class Meta:
            proxy = True

        def deactivate(self):
            if self.is_active:
                self.is_active = False
                self.save()

        def activate(self):
            if not self.is_active:
                self.is_active = True
                self.save()
```

Comment: Why not use django.contrib.auth.logout() since you are handling the rest of the functionality elsewhere.

Comment: logout() uses session.flush(), which works fine because it gets passed in that user's request object and thus session key. My case is different since I am attempting to flush all of a different user's sessions, whose keys I do not know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using Session.objects.distinct() on session_data which reduced the set from 1.3 million to about 7000 unique session_data hashes. Neat trick, but really wish Django had a prescribed solution for this.